# Problemas en rails con validaciones no existentes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bueno el problema que presento es que al agregar la gema `carrierwave-google-storage` me esta presentando problemas en toda la app ejecutando validaciones (que no existen) en toda la aplicación y son incongruentes

Ejemplo:

```
{
  "user": {
   "first_name": "nombre",
   "user_address_attributes":[
    {"name": "calle falsa123"}
   ]
 }
}
```

Respuesta:

```
"errors": {
 "user_address_attributes.user":[
  {
    "error": "blank"
  }
 ]
}
```

y así para todos los campos que tengo.

PD: "esos campos son opcionales y no tienen validaciones"

Comment: Y si agregas algo de código, no se, el modelo, el uploader que estás usando, la configuración de carrirwave. Con lo que pones no se si se pueda inferir mucho

Comment: Y si intentas pasarle [allow_blank](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) a esos atributos en el modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debía a que una de las gemas que usamos no era compatible con la versión de rails y esta rompía todo el proyecto, la solución fue especificar la versión de la gema en el gemfile.

Gema: [apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails)

Antes: `gem 'apipie-rails'`

Después: `gem 'apipie-rails', '~> 0.4.0'`